# Error TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK - RabbitMq Publiser Confirms Async Implementation

Tags: asynchronous, spring-amqp

We have implemented publisher confirms asynchronously i.e. we have setup callbacks on RabbitTemplates to get response from RabbitMq; but we are getting below exception in the logs:-

```
{"ts":"02 24 2021 14:33:21.308","th":"connectionFactory4002","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"DEBUG","logger":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl","msg":Sending confirm PendingConfirm [correlationData=CorrelationData [id=7d329ab2-2472-4222-91d0-9bc68dc405c7] cause=clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK, class-id=0, method-id=0)]  }
```

---

```
"ERROR","logger":"com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN","msg":{​​​​​[com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.waitForConfirmsOrDie(ChannelN.java:254),org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.waitForConfirmsOrDie(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:676),org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.lambda$asyncClose$1(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1371),java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142),java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617),java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]}​​​​​ ,"ERR": {​​​​​ java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.waitForConfirms(ChannelN.java:223)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.waitForConfirmsOrDie(ChannelN.java:249)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.waitForConfirmsOrDie(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:676)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.lambda$asyncClose$1(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1371)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


--Connection Factory Config
<bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value="#{messagingProperties['mq.hostname']}" />
        <property name="virtualHost" value="#{messagingProperties['mq.virtual-host']}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{messagingProperties['mq.username']}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{messagingProperties['mq.password']}" />
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="channelRpcTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="channelCacheSize" value="25" />
    </bean>
```

We have following queries regarding this :

1. How to prevent this error/log?
2. Is there message loss due to the above error?
3. Apart from resource utilization, is there any side impact of this error?
4. Do the confirmCallBack/returnCallBack call this method(waitForConfirmsOrDie) behind the scenes?

Comment: It's unusual to get this error; when physically closing a channel (rather than returning it to the cache), the framework calls `waitForConfirmsOrDie` to make sure any pending confirms are received. The fact that it is throwing an exception means the confirm was not received for some reason. You need to show your connection factory configuration to see if there are any clues. When is this happening? At runtime? Or when you are shutting down the app. Channels are normally cached and reused.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have edited my question to add connection factory config . We are seeing these error on runtime.

Comment: Try increasing the channel cache size.

Comment: Hi Gary,
 
We followed regarding TIMEOUT WAITING for ACK errors in publish and confirm with Erlang and they suggested us to increasse the transaction timeout in the clients to 65 seconds
 
We could see a way to increase the timeout value in synchronous callback like mentioned below
 
Collection<?> messages = getMessagesToSend();
Boolean result = this.template.invoke(t -> { t.waitForConfirmsOrDie( ...10_000); ...});
 
How do we increase timeout in aync callbacks flow of publish and confirm ?
 
rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlation, ack, reason) -> {}
 
Please suggest

Comment: It's currently hard coded at 5 seconds; please open a new feature suggestion: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues

Comment: Hi Gary,

Just wanted to know that in absence of publisher confirm callbacks, with channel cache size exhausted , are these TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK errors more likely to come?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: If we publish messages synchronously using Channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie​(long timeout) , will  TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK errors come after channel cache size is exhausted

Comment: If we use publish and confirms asynchronously with callbacks , we wont see this error('TIMEOUT WAITING FOR ACK')?